# bash string match in depot_tools

Tags: bash

I found code snippets in depot_tools of chromium code

```
 if [[ "#grep#fetch#cleanup#diff#" != *"#$1#"* ]]; then
     ...
 fi
```

What does it mean? Is that string match in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` denotes a positional parameter passed to the script.

The condition

```
if [[ "#grep#fetch#cleanup#diff#" != *"#$1#"* ]];
```

evaluates to `true` if the parameter is not `grep`, `fetch`, `cleanup`, or `diff`.